# Router (sometimes!) causes invalid certificate issues and applications start to malfunction

Tags: router, lan, certificate

Currently I have the following set-up at home:
[set-up of my internet connection at home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5vmh.png)
This set-up works perfectly fine most of the time. But sometimes (after a couple of hours or sometimes days) a wide range of applications start malfunctioning:

- My Outlook give the following error message (but still has internet connection):
  [Microsoft Office Outlook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Juzn.png)
- Firefox (and Chrome) give connection errors (but browsing to most sites is still possible):
- Opening a document from Sharepoint gives this error (not sure if this Moatads is linked to this issue, or another issue, or not an issue at all):
- Microsoft Office Word gives the following error, but is still working:
- Last but not least, video-calling from Microsoft Teams is no longer possible (the chat and other options still work and have connection):

**Extra information**

- If I take my LinkSys-router out of my set-up, and thus connecting my ZTE H369A directly with a LAN cable to my laptop the above-described issue **never** occurs.
- When the problem occurs, all above errors happen, it is never a sub-set of errors that take place.

**06-01-2020 Update - Certificate images:**
These certificate images are from an error message from Outlook:

- [Certificate error from Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Juzn.png)
- [General tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CECGh.png)
- [Details_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldz7l.png)
- [Details_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z5uk.png)
- [Details_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbOem.png)
- [Certification Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEhMm.png)

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: You did not show us the view certificate for the Outlook issue. So no one can tell what site it connected to. The Firefox error is similar, as all  your noted errors seem to be. That the certificate is not validated properly. This all seems to be related to your Moatads, which a search on the Internet says it is a ad/browser hijacker. Interesting it does not appear when you are directly connected.

Comment: What fixes the problem?

Comment: Switching to the set-up with no intermediate router involved 'fixes' the problem. Once I go back to the preferred set-up it works again for a couple of hours. Interestingly enough I also haven't figured out what triggers the issue above.

Comment: I assume you have tried to factory reset the Linksys router?  However, in order to diagnose the certificate issue, we really need to know more about the certificates that are being offered (**This information must be in English or translated into English**)

Comment: As soon as the issue occurs again I will try to get more details/information about the certificates

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the late reply. Due to work I had to be sure no issues would occur therefore not using my preferred set-up in a while. Today the error occured again with the certificates. I have attached all images I could make of the error message: